# VB.NET - Debug third party application

Tags: vb.net, decompiling

I'm  trying to debug my .exe file (without source) using .net reflector. I want to see if the MD5 of this file will change. The problem is that also following  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2eFk6YQRqY this I can't see the stack calls of my software, is there anything that I'm doing wrong?
I've launched the software and I've attached its process to Visual Studio. By pausing it I don't see anything in the stak calls of that .exe...

And also, the MD5 of the software will change if I try to debug it at runtime?

Thank you all

Comment: Are you asking if the act of attaching a debugger will alter the binary itself?

Comment: Your app or a third party's? Does their license allow you to decompile their assembly legally?

Comment: the .exe is mine, and I'm trying to set a breakpoint into it's source

Comment: Reflector debugging works by generating (decompiled) sources from your assembly and whipping up a PDB that maps the IL instructions to the lines in the decompiled source.  It does not alter the original assembly, so its MD5 hash will not change.